# On the Objections to Compatibilism

Tags: free-will, determinism, hume, compatibilism

I was reading An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding by David Hume, specifically the section titled On Liberty and Necessity (both parts). Hume reconciles liberty with metaphysical necessity by an ingenious argument, which I think is called the compatibilist position in the debate between determinism and free will. Essentially, Hume declares that the conflict between liberty and necessity is a verbal argument, and argues that everyone actually agrees with both the doctrine of necessity and of liberty when both are properly defined. While I usually greatly enjoy and generally agree upon Hume's philosophical expositions, I felt in this section that Hume was engaging in a kind of word jugglery, evading the actual metaphysical question. I was wondering whether any other philosophers hold this sentiment and went further to formulate serious objections towards the compatibilist doctrine.

Comment: Many of them, they are called free will libertarians. Kant was one, and took the question seriously http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24872/is-kants-noumenal-self-argument-on-freedom-flawed/24882#24882 Since compatibilism is unfalsifiable the best argument against it is that the reasons for adopting it are spurious http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/how-do-defenders-of-libertarian-freewill-define-the-boundaries-of-what-is-constr/30418#30418

Comment: Modern libertarians like Kane are briefly described and referenced here http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/how-does-quantum-mechanics-affect-the-account-of-determinism/32831#32831 Epicurus gave perhaps the shortest argument for libertarianism http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30637/why-do-modern-materialists-tend-to-favor-determinism/30640

Answer (score 1):

I consider the view of the first person (the subjective view) to hold the *libertarian* position and the view of the third person (the objective view) to hold the *determinist* position.

The *compatibilist* position is the view of most neuroscientists. They strive to resolve the opposites between both other views: To keep the subjective view, but to explain it by a deterministic approach.

A good introduction is *Walter, Henrik: Neurophilosophy of free will: from libertarian illusions to a concept of natural autonomy* (2001).

Comment: `The compatibilist position is the view of most neuroscientists` - I would love a source for this. I googled it and can't find any confirmation.